# 'Validating the security token of this form has failed. Please reload the form and submit it again.'

Tags: typo3

I uploaded a picture and then tried to delete it, and I got this message:

> Validating the security token of this form has failed. Please reload the form and submit it again.

What can I do to delete the picture and not get this error message?

Comment: Reloading the form or relogin to the backend does not help?

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the security token just expired (session time over?) - try clearing cache and reloading or even better relogin to the backend as Simon Gilli already mentioned it.